# How do i run JBehave tests with Maven?

Tags: maven, bdd, jbehave

How do i run JBehave tests from Maven?
I have a class that extends JUnitStories which runs from my IDE.
I cant get JBehave Maven plugin to run my tests.
Can anyone point to a simple way to run tests with Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know Mauro and Paul have already responded to you in the JBehave group, so I'm going to put their responses here for completeness:

> In the interim, you can [refer to the tutorial](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-tutorial), which provides a
>   simplified example (although complete) with one way to run stories via
>   Maven.

2018 edit: JBehave now supports [Maven's archetypes](https://jbehave.org/reference/stable/archetypes.html):

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=org.jbehave:jbehave
```

The archetype `jbehave-simple-archetype` (listed from this command) provides a simple way to get started.

Comment: Hi Sathish, I want to apologise for not doing more on this. As always, other commitments have gotten in the way of my fun. I think from your list posts that you've got it working now?

Answer (score 0):

If your project is based on JBehave project archetype, then you just need to run "mvn integration-test"